Redis Sessions not getting properly deleted by Spring Security / Spring Session
When I run this:
@Component
internal class SessionServerLogoutHandler(
    private val sessionControl: SessionControl,
    private val webSessionStore: SpringSessionWebSessionStore<ReactiveRedisIndexedSessionRepository.RedisSession>,
    private val sessionProperties: SessionProperties,
    private val csrfProperties: CsrfProperties,
) : ServerLogoutHandler {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionServerLogoutHandler::class.java)

    override fun logout(exchange: WebFilterExchange, authentication: Authentication?): Mono<Void> {
        return exchange.exchange.session
            .flatMap { session ->
                logger.info("Logging out: Invalidating User Session: ${session.id}")

                val response = exchange.exchange.response

                // invalidate and delete session
                webSessionStore.removeSession(session.id)
                    .then(Mono.fromRunnable {

                        logger.info("Deleting Session Cookie: ${sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME}")

                        // delete the session cookie
                        val sessionCookie = ResponseCookie.from(sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME)
                        .maxAge(0)
                        .httpOnly(sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY)
                        .secure(sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE)
                        .sameSite(sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_SAME_SITE)
                        .path(sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_PATH)
                        .domain(sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN)
                        .build()
                        response.headers.add(
                            HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE,
                            sessionCookie.toString()
                        )

                        logger.info("Deleting Session Cookie: ${csrfProperties.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME}")

                        // delete the CSRF cookie
                        val csrfCookie = ResponseCookie.from(csrfProperties.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME)
                        .maxAge(0)
                        .httpOnly(csrfProperties.CSRF_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY)
                        .secure(csrfProperties.CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE)
                        .sameSite(csrfProperties.CSRF_COOKIE_SAME_SITE)
                        .path(csrfProperties.CSRF_COOKIE_PATH)
                        .domain(csrfProperties.CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN)
                        .build()
                        response.headers.add(
                            HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE,
                            csrfCookie.toString()
                        )
                    })
            }
    }
}

The key line is:
webSessionStore.removeSession(session.id)

Springs own low level implementation of this is, inside the class SpringSessionWebSessionStore, is this:
@Override
public Mono<Void> removeSession(String sessionId) {
    return this.sessions.deleteById(sessionId);
}

Their class can be found here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/main/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/server/session/SpringSessionWebSessionStore.java
All I see in Redis is:

And then after running the logout handler:

Am I meant to run another function. Is this really expected behaviour - to leave the key in Redis?
A lot of my code will throw serialisation errors if it sees a key (user session actually exists), but has only the lastAccessedDate attribute - e.g. when checking if a user is authenticated when getting their session, and checking the security context attribute.
I can't see much that I may have done wrong myself. Maybe I need to call some other function?
Or directly use RedisOperations or RedisTemplate?
Rather than this.sessions.deleteById(sessionId), which is really
reactiveRedisIndexedSessionRepository.deleteById(sessionId)

Still, the above should work, right?
This part of the Spring repository code, ReactiveRedisIndexedSessionRepository, just doesn't work for me. Nothing gets deleted...
private Mono<RedisSession> deleteAndReturn(String id) {
        // @formatter:off
        return getSession(id, true)
                .flatMap((session) -> this.sessionRedisOperations.delete(getExpiredKey(session.getId()))
                        .thenReturn(session))
                .flatMap((session) -> this.sessionRedisOperations.delete(getSessionKey(session.getId())).thenReturn(session))
                .flatMap((session) -> this.indexer.delete(session.getId()).thenReturn(session))
                .flatMap((session) -> this.expirationStore.remove(session.getId()).thenReturn(session));
        // @formatter:on
    }

